# How to save file on vuex to upload it later

Tags: file, vue.js, vuex

I want to select an image file and save on VUEX to upload it later with sending it to a API Endpoint, I try this concept and select a file with `input:file` and save it to `this.file` then I save it to a state in VUEX somehow, but when I want to get file data from VUEX it just returns an empty object

```
<input type="file" id="uploadImage" @change="selectFile">
```

```
data() {
    return {
        file: null
    }
},

methods: {
    selectFile(event) {
        this.file = event.target.files[0];
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `multiple` in input tag, `this.files` should be an Array of File objects

```
<input type="file" id="uploadImage" ref="myFiles" class="custom-file-input" 
      @change="selectFile" multiple>

data() {
  return {
    files: [],
  }
},
methods: {
  selectFile() {
    this.files = this.$refs.myFiles.files
  }
}
```